# javascript: how to scroll a small pop-up window

Tags: javascript, scroll, popup, window, instagram

I am currently trying to create a javascript bot, for Instagram, that follows users based on the list of "followers" a user has. I am currently trying to use the **Window scrollBy() method** to scroll down a small pop-up window that appears when you click following. It would be best if you saw what I am trying to describe as popup window, by nagivating to

instagram.com/instagram

and clicking "followers"

I am not sure if its possible to scroll that small window. Please let me know if it. Currently, the window scrollBy will move the page down, but not the scroll bar in the center, that I'd like it to!

All feedback and code clean-up are appreciated, as I am stilling pretty new with javascript! Thank you!

```
    for(var i=0;i<3;i++) {
    (function(i) {
    setInterval(clickButton(i), 2000);
    }) (i)
    }
    function clickButton(idx) {
    return function() {
    buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('_aj7mu _2hpcs _95tat _o0442');
    document.getElementsByClassName('_aj7mu _2hpcs _95tat _o0442')[idx].click();
    window.scrollBy(0, 100);
        }
    }
```

NOTE: I am trying to make this work in Google Chrome Console. Not sure if this will change any responses.

Answer (score 2):

To scroll that element down just declare a variable with its reference:

```
var popup = document.getElementsByClassName('_4gt3b');
```

and use the element property scrollTop to define its scroll bar distance from the top:

```
 popup[0].scrollTop = y;
```

where y is a variable that you will declare with an integer value in it.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a scrollBottom method? I can't seem to find one. How would I define scrolling downwards instead of upwards? Negative integers don't seem to work.

Comment: No, a scrollBottom method does not exist, why would you need one though? just add the index of your for cycle to the expression so whenever the index increase the scroll bar scrolls down:  popup[0].scrollTop = y * i; if the question solved your issue mark it as accepted